# Новый цикл отрисовки в блокирующей функции IMGui

Tags: c++, render

У меня есть основной цикл приложения, который вызывает `IMGui::Render()`. Все кнопки и т.д. между началом фрейма и концом отрисовываются нормально. По нажатию одной из кнопок вызывается функция, которая по определенному условию должна запрашивать у пользователя ответ на вопрос (отрисовывать текст `IMGui::Text()` и две кнопки `IMGui::Button()` - ответы "да" и "нет"). Как можно подобное осуществить, ведь эта функция блокирует основной поток отрисовки? То есть основной поток отрисовки должен как бы замораживаться и должен отрисовываться только вопрос с кнопками из функции.

Если переместить отрисовку в основной поток по значению флага (если установлен флаг из функции, то рисуем вопрос в основном потоке), то тогда после установки флага нужно всё равно выйти из функции, отрисовать, но вернуться потом в неё не получится.

Единственное, что приходит на ум, это корутины: вызываем функцию, она устанавливает флаг и завершается, основной поток рисует кнопки вопроса, пока пользователь не ответит. А после того как ответит, возвращаемся в нужное место функции. Но тогда нужно библиотеку подключать, да и вообще усложнять программу.

Возможно, стоит создать дополнительное окно для отрисовки этого вопроса и ловли нажатия кнопок пользователем в самой функции?

Ещё, как вариант, запускать функцию в отдельном потоке, чтобы не блокировать отрисовку. Но тогда нужна синхронизация - опять же усложняет код.

Наверняка, подобное поведение нужно часто и есть какие-то решения в `IMGUi`. В `issues` не нашёл.

**upd:**

пока что заставил работать с помощью вызова функции в другом потоке

Comment: @HolyBlackCat может вы знаете? (видел вас в тредах по IMGui :))

Comment: Вы делаете много лишних действий. ImGui - **immediate gui**, зачем выдумывать костыли? Запустите `ImGui::ShowDemoWindow()`, там полно примеров, есть и MsgBox'ы

Answer (score 0):

Упрощенный пример из документации по `ImGui` (imgui_demo.cpp):

```
if (ImGui::Button("Click me"))
    ImGui::OpenPopup("Click me");

if (ImGui::BeginPopupModal("Click me", NULL, ImGuiWindowFlags_AlwaysAutoResize))
{
    ImGui::Text(u8"Поставить плюс этому ответу?");
    ImGui::Separator();

    if (ImGui::Button(u8"Да", ImVec2(120, 0))) { 
        // нажато "Да"
        ImGui::CloseCurrentPopup(); 
    }
    ImGui::SetItemDefaultFocus();
    ImGui::SameLine();
    if (ImGui::Button(u8"Нет", ImVec2(120, 0))) { 
        // нажато "Нет"
        ImGui::CloseCurrentPopup(); 
    }
    ImGui::EndPopup();
}
```

Comment: вы не поняли, что я хочу. Мне нужно то, что вы написали, в блокирующей функции некоторого класса не из основного потока отрисовки.